# How to overwrite existing Cookie with new value in PHP?

Tags: php, cookies, session-cookies, setcookie

I have been searching on how to overwrite a certain cookies value like for example in user's information. how can I call the cookie back to the client matched on the user's input. for the cookie to change its value?

Comment: Check here: http://ar.php.net/manual/es/function.setcookie.php
It is very important to understand that you sending a HEADER and needs to be done before any output.

Answer (score 8):

You can only overwrite cookies that you have access to modify.  If you are setting a cookie yourself with `setcookie()` the same functionality will overwrite that cookie.

Cookies must be modified before any data is sent to the browser.  The browser identifies a cookie and stores it based on headers sent from the server to the browser.  The HTTP protocol will not accept header elements during transmission of the body.